# How do I call Matlab in a script on Windows?

Tags: windows, matlab, scripting, automation

I'm working on a project that uses several languages:

- SQL for querying a database
- Perl/Ruby for quick-and-dirty processing of the data from the database and some other bookkeeping
- Matlab for matrix-oriented computations
- Various statistics languages (SAS/R/SPSS) for processing the Matlab output

Each language fits its niche well and we already have a fair amount of code in each.  Right now, there's a lot of manual work to run all these steps that would be much better scripted.  I've already done this on Linux, and it works relatively well.

On Linux:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "command"
```

or

```
echo "command" | matlab -nosplash -nodesktop
```

...opens Matlab in a "command line" mode.  (That is, no windows are created -- it just reads from STDIN, executes, and outputs to STDOUT/STDERR.)  My problem is that on Windows (XP and 7), this same code opens up a window and doesn't read from / write to the command line.  It just stares me blankly in the face, totally ignoring STDIN and STDOUT.

How can I script running Matlab commands on Windows?  I basically want something that will do:

```
ruby database_query.rb
perl legacy_code.pl
ruby other_stuff.rb
matlab processing_step_1.m
matlab processing_step_2.m
# etc, etc.
```

I've found out that Matlab has an `-automation` flag on Windows to start an ["automation server"](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html).  That sounds like overkill for my purposes, and I'd like something that works on both platforms.

What options do I have for automating Matlab in this workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "command"
```

works on Windows as well. Yes, it opens another window, but it's not a problem. I run it in a batch mode from Java wrapper on Tomcat server and there were no issues. Put all commands into a script file, don't forget to close the session with exit command, and use -r flag. Also you can find **-noFigureWindows** and **-wait** parameters useful. And it works on both Windows and Unix. You can use platform-specific flags, if some are not supported they will be ignored.

[Start MATLAB program (Windows platforms)](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/matlabwindows.html)

There is also a way to hide matlab window with C library. See [engSetVisible](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/apiref/engsetvisible.html).

Comment: Hrm... maybe I was leaving something out.  I'll have to check it on Windows again.  Thanks for your help!